# LSTM model performs worse adding more data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm

My LSTM model is configured as follows:

- Input: 60 measurements of the same float feature over time (cell dim = 60)
- Output: 3 classes
- Training and validation function: cross entropy with softmax
- Optimizer: Adam
- Learning rate: 0.0005
- Batch size: 180 (3 sequences)

The classes have the following distribution in the training and test datasets:

```
A = 49.5%, B = 49.5%, C = 1%
```

Class C rarely occurs and I'm only interested in classes A and B.

During the training, the validation loss has an **opposite trend** to the training loss, and in some points they seem perfectly specular.
Also, I've noticed that the precision and recall improve when the training loss falls below a certain threshold, but that's generally where the validation loss is high.

**What could be causing this behavior?**

I started with 25 layers and saw this behavior, suspecting overfitting I progressively decreased the layers

[image]

**25 LSTM layers, 1500 training samples, 1500 test samples, best F1 score = 0.564**
[image]

**6 LSTM layers, 1500 training samples, 1500 test samples, best F1 score = 0.569**
[image]

**1 LSTM layers, 1500 training samples, 1500 test samples, best F1 score = 0.639**
[image]
Therefore, since the confusion matrix and consequent F1 remained very similar to the previous training (if not better), I kept on only 1 layer to reduce the complexity of the model. Since testing this on a larger number of test samples (about a million) the F1 score was very poor, I thought of adding progressively more training and test data, also hoping that this it would have improved any overfitting issues.

**1 LSTM layers, 3000 training samples, 3000 test samples, best F1 score = 0.568**
[image]
Since with 3000 training samples, the F1 score is similar to the previous model, but still poor when tested on a larger dataset I tried to add even more data.

**1 LSTM layers, 6000 training samples, 6000 test samples, best F1 score = 0.320**
[image]

And here is the **real problem**: even if the training and validation loss are similar to previous models, the **F1 is very low and does not seem to improve**, even by increasing the learning rate.

On this dataset I also tried to add L1 and L2 regularization, but they seem to have the only effect of reaching the same F1 score in fewer epochs. Adding dropouts I didn't notice any improvements. I also tried varying the batch size and learning rate, but I always got very similar results.

**In short**

- Is the divergence between the training loss and the test loss normal?
- Why doesn't the model seem to work anymore when on a 6000 sample dataset?
- What can I do to maintain the previously obtained F1 score even on the dataset of 6000 samples?